# Facebook query Language

Tags: java, javascript

How can I use FQl(facebook query language ) in my application to

1. GetOnline friends
2. Get Images
3. Upload Photos

and more features

Comment: Not sure if this is related to Java

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found uses php.

```
<?php   

 $facebook_config['debug'] = false;

    $facebook_config['api_key'] = '<your_api_key>';

    $facebook_config['secret_key'] = '<your_secret_key>';


    require_once('<path_to_client_library>/facebook.php');

    $facebook = new Facebook($facebook_config['api_key'], $facebook_config['secret']);


    $user = $facebook->require_login();

    $friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_get();

    echo "<pre>Friends:" . print_r($friends, true). "</pre>";

?>
```

- Code from Facebook API Developers Guide by WAYNE GRAHAM